# How to create a SQL Server query to do validation against preexisting look up (base) table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, lookup, radix

I have customer some customer records in which one of the fields is country.

Say below are the records and column A is customer number, column be is customer name and column C is country

```
CNumber  CName     CCountry
-----------------------------
0001     CustomerA USA
0002     CustomerB Japan
0003     CustomerC France
0004     CustomerD Hoss
```

In the SQL server database, there is already a tabled name COUNTRY which has all the countries there is listed there. What would be the query to compare that all the customers have a valid country name in column C. Like we can see customer 0004 has the country Hoss which is not a country. I need the query to tell me its an invalid country for the 0004 customer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: From a design perspective, you should have a unique country id in your `country` table. Column C should contain that ID, and it should contain a foreign key so that you can only store valid country id's

Comment: i get the part that the id in the country table should be unique, i also get column c should be that country id. but dont get the part "and it should contain a foreign key so that you can only store valid country id's –" do you mean column c will be the foreign key? Thanks.

Comment: Yes column C will be a foreign key. I suggest that you Google "t-sql foreign key" or read about them more generally here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list all the records with invalid country

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer
 WHERE CCountry NOT IN (SELECT CCountry
                          FROM country)
```

Comment: thank you i will try this and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just want to know what customers have a country which is not in the country table. this tells you that:

```
   SELECT  *
    FROM    CUSTOMER
    WHERE   CUSTOMER.COUNTRY NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM COUNTRY)
```

You could edit this to only return the ids of customers with invalid countries:

```
   SELECT   CUSTOMER.ID
    FROM    CUSTOMER
    WHERE   CUSTOMER.COUNTRY NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM COUNTRY)
```

Or perhaps the country and id they customer has used. Then you could give a custom error message: *"John unfortunately the country you specified: "asdf"* is invalid."

Comment: thank you i will try this and let you know how it goes.